# How to get from html the element of a register field by Name?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a register program :
For example:
Button1 click event:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.Navigate("register site");
    wb.Document.GetElementById("passwort").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
    wb.Document.GetElementById("register").InvokeMember("click");
```

Here is the register page html code ( From view source ) :

```
<td><h5>Password:<br><input type="password" name="passwort"></td> 
<td> <input type="submit" name="register" value="Registri"></td>
```

Is there any chance to get the element by his name?because it has no ID .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the elements directly by name, but you could access it by finding the input tags first, and indexing into the result to find the tags by name.

`wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")["passwort"]`

Comment: I get at your code : error : Only one assigment,increment etc.. and new object expression can be used as a statment

Comment: The code above will return the right element - you still need to do something with it:


`var passwordElement = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")["passwort"];
passwordElement.SetAttribute("value", "your_password");`